# getting dummy values acorss all columns

Tags: pandas

get dummies method does not seem to work as expected while using with more than one column.
For e.g. if I have this dataframe...

```
shopping_list = [
    ["Apple", "Bread", "Fridge"],
    ["Rice", "Bread", "Milk"],
    ["Apple", "Rice", "Bread", "Milk"],
    ["Rice", "Milk"],
    ["Apple", "Bread", "Milk"],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(shopping_list)
```

If I use get_dummmies method, the items are repeated across columns like this:

```
pd.get_dummies(df)

    0_Apple 0_Rice  1_Bread 1_Milk  1_Rice  2_Bread 2_Fridge    2_Milk  3_Milk
0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0
2   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1
3   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
4   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0
```

While the expected result is:

```
    Apple Bread Fridge Milk Rice
0 1 1 1 0 0 
1 0 1 0 1 1
2 1 1 0 1 1
3 0 0 0 1 1
4 1 1 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parameters `prefix` and `prefix_sep` to [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and then add `max` for avoid duplicated columns names (it aggregate by `max`):

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix='', prefix_sep='').max(axis=1, level=0)
print(df)

   Apple  Rice  Bread  Milk  Fridge
0      1     0      1     0       1
1      0     1      1     1       0
2      1     1      1     1       0
3      0     1      0     1       0
4      1     0      1     1       0
```